# Tab Bar Controller items start from the right

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to make tab bar's items to start from the right.
I mean like:

**A tab of objects:**

> 1 2 3 4

**Would be like:**

> 4 3 2 1

**But when i do it visually it makes it:**

> 1 2 3 4

**when the items look visualy as:**

> 4 3 2 1

I want it to open with the **1** on (the rightest option)

Any help will be helpfull !
Thanks :)

Comment: Are you creating your tabbar: a) Programatically b) Using Interface Builder c) Using Storyboard?

Comment: Using Storyboard on a xib file. i think it is... or Interface Builder... not so sure... it's an wp app i bought and it's ltr so i am trying to make it rtl'd

Comment: Storyboards are on .storyboards files, you have picked the option b.

Comment: I wasn't the one who build it. I am just fixing it. (making changes, new to iOS development)
it is a .xib file

Comment: Ok, i'll add an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, what you do is ignore the settings in you interfacebuilder.

In your `AppDelegate.m` you are initiating the `UITabbarController` most likely... and change it to something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController4 = [[FourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController4, viewController3, viewController2, viewController1];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

This should make your tabs show in the order 4, 3, 2, 1.

Comment: how would the `AppDelegate.h` would look? according to this `AppDelegate.m`?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand your question. The `AppDelegate.m` file is the file that is auto-generated when creating the project. In older projects it usually is call `ProjectNameAppDelegate.m` (Hence the starting with the project name).

Comment: thats the problem... i don't have one. so i added it. but it gives me some errors because you need to declare on the objects or something... what to sign in the appdelegate.h?

Comment: You *should* have one, I believe. Search for e.g. `UIApplicationDelegate` and see if you find your delegate class.

Answer (score 0):

Order your tab bar items, if its in the xib file or if it was create programmatically in code. To set the first tab to be on the left side set the tabbar controller selected item at index 0, and if you want it to start from right set index at the last tabbar item.